# d3.js window.open doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, d3.js, window.open

I need to open the urls in a new tab or window. Right now they are opening in the same page.

```
var data = [
{title: "1", url: "gallery1.html"},
{title: "2", url: "gallery2.html"},
{title: "3", url: "gallery3.html"},
];



    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.example.url; })
    .attr("xlink:title", function(d) { return d.example.title; });

svg.selectAll('.add-url-node')
   .on('click',function(d){
      location.href = 'target.url.com';

   });
```

I tried:

```
<script>    
window.open(url);      
</script>
```

and

```
window.open(link, "_blank")
```

and

```
data.forEach(function(elem){
window.open(elem.url,"_blank");
});
```

and

```
.attr("xlink:target", "_blank")
```

I have no programming experience, I would really appreciate to see an example using the code above. many thanks.

Comment: `window.open(d.url)` is working for me.

Comment: Where? I'm trying to put that rather than: location.href ="target.url.com"; and it still open in same tab.

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? Does it open in the same tab?

Comment: I did check and It does open in a new tab. Your rectangles work fine for me, but i'm not able to integrate that into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.attr("target","_blank", function(d) { return d.example.url; })
```

This is what I needed,
Thanks everybody anyway

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the use of `location.href`. If you want the link to open in a new tab or window, and not in the same tab (page), you need to use `window.open()`:

```
selection.on('click',function(){
  window.open(url)
});
```

Note: You cannot force a link to open in a new tab instead of a new window. It's a **user preference**.

Check this fiddle, I created 3 rectangles, and binded data to them with some links. Click on each rectangle to open the link: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/9s7wpb20/1/

Comment: I'm trying to use your code, but i'm only able to open my links in a new tab by clicking on your rectangles. My d3.js still opening in same tab.

Comment: Let me understand: in the fiddle, is it opening in a new tab or in the same tab?

Comment: in your fiddle, it is opening in a new tab. but i'm not able to do the same with my code.

Comment: I changed my: location.href = 'target.url.com';  for your: window.open(d.url)

Comment: Just that change? My fiddle is just an example, depending on your real code you're gonna make a lot of changes...

Comment: like? I'm not a coder but I think the part of the code I put at the begining is the only part of the code that is actually involved in opening the urls.

Comment: That code you put is not sufficient: what are those `attr`? What is the selection? How is the data being binded? You see, there is a lot of details. Try to create a fiddle, a codepen or a plunker with a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kajihood/4ucgLju0/ It took me one hour just to do this fiddle,  so that should give you an idea of my skill level.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean with "where is add-url-node". That is just the code i have to make this work. And I put back location.href because I thought it would be better to show the original code...

Comment: If you are modifying the code at "D3js.org", pay attention to *how* they do it.